# JS Filter Not Working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently developing a landing page website for a client to display a range of products.

I have created a filter in JS to filter some products but its not working.

The two radios are tagged with Motorola and when you select the Motorola it doesn't show them?

I would appreciate any help someone can give me.

I am not the most confident with javascript

```
<div class="container mg-b-40">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <aside class="sidebar">
        <h5 class="heading-primary">Filter</h5>
        <ul class="shop-filters">
            <li class="filter">
                <input type="checkbox" value="motorola" id="motorola">
                <label for="motorola">Motorola</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filter">
                <input type="checkbox" value="hytera" id="hytera">
                <label for="hytera">Hytera</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filter">
                <input type="checkbox" value="icom" id="icom">
                <label for="icom">Icom</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filter">
                <input type="checkbox" value="vertex" id="vertex">
                <label for="vertex">Vertex</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filter">
                <input type="checkbox" value="kenwood" id="kenwood">
                <label for="kenwood">Kenwood</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filter">
                <input type="checkbox" value="savox" id="savox">
                <label for="savox">Savox</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="masonry-loader masonry-loader-showing">
            <div class="row products product-thumb-info-list mt-3" data-plugin-masonry data-plugin-options="{'layoutMode': 'fitRows'}">
                <div class="category motorola">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12 product">
                        <a href="shop-product-sidebar.html"></a>
                        <span class="product-thumb-info">
                            <span class="product-thumb-info-image">
                                <img alt="" class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1148/2692/products/dp1400-01_Radio_Shop_UK_b113f82f-a13b-4ffa-93fd-612f313084ef.jpg?v=1529421291">
                            </span>
                            <span class="product-thumb-info-content">
                                <h4 class="heading-brand">Motorola DP1400</h4>
                                <div class="btn-group action-group" role="group" aria-label="Action Buttons">
                                    <a href="tel:0800 774 7147" class="btn btn-primary btn-buy">Call Now</a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-buy" rel=”nofollow”>Buy Now</a>
                                </div>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category hytera">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12 product">
                        <a href="shop-product-sidebar.html"></a>
                        <span class="product-thumb-info">
                            <span class="product-thumb-info-image">
                                <img alt="" class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1148/2692/products/dp1400-01_Radio_Shop_UK_b113f82f-a13b-4ffa-93fd-612f313084ef.jpg?v=1529421291">
                            </span>
                            <span class="product-thumb-info-content">
                                <h4 class="heading-brand">Motorola DP1400</h4>
                                <div class="btn-group action-group" role="group" aria-label="Action Buttons">
                                    <a href="tel:0800 774 7147" class="btn btn-primary btn-buy">Call Now</a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-buy" rel=”nofollow”>Buy Now</a>
                                </div>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>

$(':input').change(function(evt){

var filter = $(':input:checked,select').map(function(index, el) {
    return "." + el.value;
}).toArray().join("");

$(".product").hide().filter(filter).show();

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're hiding `.product`, but actual item to be hidden is `.category`. See below the working demo.

```js
$(':input').change(function(evt) {
  var filter = $(':input:checked, select').map(function(_, el) {
    return "." + el.value;
  }).toArray().join("");

  $(".category").hide().filter(filter).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mg-b-40">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <aside class="sidebar">
        <h5 class="heading-primary">Filter</h5>
        <ul class="shop-filters">
          <li class="filter">
            <input type="checkbox" value="motorola" id="motorola">
            <label for="motorola">Motorola</label>
          </li>
          <li class="filter">
            <input type="checkbox" value="hytera" id="hytera">
            <label for="hytera">Hytera</label>
          </li>
          <li class="filter">
            <input type="checkbox" value="icom" id="icom">
            <label for="icom">Icom</label>
          </li>
          <li class="filter">
            <input type="checkbox" value="vertex" id="vertex">
            <label for="vertex">Vertex</label>
          </li>
          <li class="filter">
            <input type="checkbox" value="kenwood" id="kenwood">
            <label for="kenwood">Kenwood</label>
          </li>
          <li class="filter">
            <input type="checkbox" value="savox" id="savox">
            <label for="savox">Savox</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div class="masonry-loader masonry-loader-showing">
        <div class="row products product-thumb-info-list mt-3" data-plugin-masonry data-plugin-options="{'layoutMode': 'fitRows'}">
          <div class="category motorola">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12 product">
              <a href="shop-product-sidebar.html"></a>
              <span class="product-thumb-info">
                            <span class="product-thumb-info-image">
                                <img alt="" class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1148/2692/products/dp1400-01_Radio_Shop_UK_b113f82f-a13b-4ffa-93fd-612f313084ef.jpg?v=1529421291">
                            </span>
              <span class="product-thumb-info-content">
                                <h4 class="heading-brand">Motorola DP1400</h4>
                                <div class="btn-group action-group" role="group" aria-label="Action Buttons">
                                    <a href="tel:0800 774 7147" class="btn btn-primary btn-buy">Call Now</a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-buy" rel=”nofollow”>Buy Now</a>
                                </div>
                            </span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="category hytera">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12 product">
              <a href="shop-product-sidebar.html"></a>
              <span class="product-thumb-info">
                            <span class="product-thumb-info-image">
                                <img alt="" class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1148/2692/products/dp1400-01_Radio_Shop_UK_b113f82f-a13b-4ffa-93fd-612f313084ef.jpg?v=1529421291">
                            </span>
              <span class="product-thumb-info-content">
                                <h4 class="heading-brand">Hytera</h4>
                                <div class="btn-group action-group" role="group" aria-label="Action Buttons">
                                    <a href="tel:0800 774 7147" class="btn btn-primary btn-buy">Call Now</a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-buy" rel=”nofollow”>Buy Now</a>
                                </div>
                            </span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```